# How do I get the column letter of a single row where a particular value equals a test value?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

[image]

I need to get the letter of the column that has a value in a given row that matches a given value in Google Sheets, assuming that no values in the row are duplicates.

For example, in the above screenshot, if the row is the first row, and the test value is `Jun`, the formula will return `H`.

Kind of meta.  Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Answer

The following formula should produce the behaviour you desire:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("Jun",A1:1),4),"[1-9]*",)
```

### Explanation

The `=MATCH` formula returns the position of the item in a range which has a specified value. In this case, the specified value is `"Jun"` and the range is `A1:1`.

`=ADDRESS` returns the A1 notation of a row and column specified by its number. In this case, the row is `1` and the column is whichever number is returned by the `=MATCH`. The `4` is there so that `=ADDRESS` returns `H1` instead of `$H$1` (absolute reference is its default).

`=REGEXREPLACE` looks through a string for a specified pattern and replaces that portion of the string with another string. In this case, the pattern to search for is any number. The last argument of `=REGEXREPLACE` is blank so it simply removes all numbers from the string.

What is left is the letter of the column where the value is found.

Functions Used:

- [=MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en)
- [=ADDRESS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093308?hl=en)
- [=REGEXREPLACE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245?hl=en)

Comment: Dude.  That is perfect.  I was missing the `MATCH`.  Clever use of `REGEXREPLACE`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Now that Google Sheets has added Named Functions, there is an easier way to do this.

To use named functions, go to `Data -> Σ Named Functions`. A sidebar will pop up. At the bottom use "Add new function" to create a new named function.

I created two functions to do this:
First, `COL_CHAR` which will take a column reference and return its letter
Second, `ALPHA_CHAR` which takes a numeric input and converts it to letters. I made this one recursive, so if it's an n-letter column name, it will keep calling itself until it gets the full name.

`COL_CHAR` just converts the referenced column to a column number and passes that to `ALPHA_CHAR`. It's formula is:

```
=ALPHA_CHAR( column(cell) )
```

where `cell` is an Argument placeholder. Make sure to add that to the argument placeholder list in the sidebar.

Here is the (recursive) formula for `ALPHA_CHAR`:

```
=IF( num > 26, ALPHA_CHAR( INT( num / 26 ) ), "") & CHAR( CODE("A") - 1 + MOD( num, 26 ) )
```

where `num` is an Argument placeholder.

By making this recursive, even if Google Sheets expands to allow 4-letter (or more) columns in the future, it will keep iterating through every letter regardless of how many there is.

Then, to get the letter of a column in the spreadsheet, you just call `COL_CHAR` and pass the cell in the column you want, for example:

```
= COL_CHAR(BK1)
```

Will return the string "BK"